# Parameter conditions "dietaryrestrictionssearches" not met for actual request parameters: active={304, 305}

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mysql-workbench

my controller and model. I check two checkboxes and it should put those values 30 and 305 into table but I get this message. Any help would be appreciated

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST, params = {"dietaryrestrictionssearches"})
    public String processUserDietaryRestrictions(@ModelAttribute @Valid User newUser,

                                    @RequestBody List<Integer> dietaryrestrictionssearches,
                                    Errors errors, Model model) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "AddUserRestriction");
            return "add";
        }

        if (!dietaryrestrictionssearches.isEmpty()) {

            List<DietaryRestrictionsSearch> drsObjs = (List<DietaryRestrictionsSearch>) dietaryRestrictionsRepository.findAllById(dietaryrestrictionssearches);
            if (!drsObjs.isEmpty()) {
                newUser.setDietaryrestrictionssearches(drsObjs);
            }
            userRepository.save(newUser);
            return "redirect:/selection/" + newUser.getId();
        }
        return "redirect:../add";
    }


@Entity
public class DietaryRestrictionsSearch {

    @Id
    private int restrict_id;

    @Column
    private String restrictions;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="dietaryrestrictionssearches")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public DietaryRestrictionsSearch() {}


    public DietaryRestrictionsSearch(String restrictions, int restrict_id) {
        super();
        this.restrictions = restrictions;
        this.restrict_id = restrict_id;
    }
  //getters and setters
```

Comment: I looked at your comments but don't see any added information. Did you make a change of some kind? Sorry if I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The message says that you are sending 1 parameter with name 'active' with that values, but the endpoint /add require also a parameter called dietaryrestrictionssearches so it does not satisfy the request.

If what you send is right and you don't need that dietaryrestrictionssearches , simply change it in a @RequestParam (name ="dietaryrestrictionssearches ")

Ivan